# How to configure ruby version a gem uses?

Tags: ruby

```
ruby -v
```

ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636)

```
which ruby
```

/usr/local/bin/ruby

yet third-party gems i've installed are sourced from

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/{gem-folder/...}
```

I'm concerned that my runtimes are different? evaluating with ruby 2.2.3 using modules sourced from ruby 2.2.0? Is that possible?

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/
```

only contains the folder `2.2.0`

**Is there a way to install gems for a different ruby version?**

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but are you using something like rvm or brew to manage your ruby versions?